# python-gitlab api SSL bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, gitlab

I want to list all the issues in a github repository.

Python3 code:

```py
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://git.myinternalsite.com/project', private_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', api_version=4) 

issues = gl.issues.list()
```

This generates the following error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='git.zonetrading.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cloudquant/user-issues/api/v4/issues (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

Any ideas on how to correct the error?

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate?

Comment: Is it because of https://twitter.com/bradfitz/status/950932394407702528?

Comment: Not using a self-signed certificate. The only thing not shown is that the private token was created on our internal gitlab installation (XXXXX was provided). I did try using UID and PWD and got the same SSLError.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be a faulty configured webserver.

The TLS certificate is only certified for the domain `www.parkingcrew.com`and not for `git.zonetrading.com` this leads to the `certificate verify failed`error.

To fix this you have to request a new certificate which includes the target domain, in this case `git.zonetrading.com`.

To confirm this is the only error, you can turn off the certificate verification in the client using the `ssl_verify` parameter.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://git.myinternalsite.com/project', private_token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', api_version=4, ssl_verify=False)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass that parameter here.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the feedback everyone.
Here is how I ended up solving this:

Additional info... our enterprise github doesn't have a proper certificate, so warnings were generated.

```
##########################################
# Dump one ticket to screen so you can see
# all the fields available.
##########################################
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()

c = pycurl.Curl()

#
# using a private token from git. Had to register my token
# as a function within the github user profile settings
#
private_token = 'private_token=XXXXXMyPrivateTokenXXXXX'

#
# projects/3 - I had to dump the project list to find the id number 
# of the project that I wanted to get all the issues for
#
GitAPIurl = 'https://git.****MyDomain***.com/api/v4/projects/3/issues?{}'.format(private_token)

c.setopt(c.URL,GitAPIurl)
# turn off SSL verification because we don't have a proper SSL Certification
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = []

body = buffer
# Body is a byte string.
# We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
# such as standard output.

foo = {}
dictionary = json.loads(buffer.getvalue())
foo = dictionary[0]

print(foo)
```

Comment: your solution is 42 lines. if you use the `gitlab` python module you may be able to solve this with 1 line of code: `import gitlab; print gitlab.Gitlab*projects*issue*`. or you may even just use the `gitlab` command line tool (also provided by the python-gitlab pip install. the python-gitlab takes care of the HTTP API and makes it 10x easier so you write less lines of code.